# How to find temporal overlap in a time-indexed DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a DataFrame in which the index is a date_time and the data in the columns is interleaved over time. Perhaps the best explanation would be to show this DF:

```
>>> c
                     A           B          C          D
2015-01-01  0.09607408         NaN        NaN        NaN
2015-01-02         NaN  0.03582221        NaN        NaN
2015-01-03   0.2750026         NaN        NaN        NaN
2015-01-04         NaN    0.892619        NaN        NaN
2015-01-05   0.8574456         NaN        NaN        NaN
2015-01-06         NaN  0.08720886        NaN        NaN
2015-01-07   0.7091732         NaN        NaN        NaN
2015-01-08         NaN  0.09354087        NaN        NaN
2015-01-09     0.60924         NaN        NaN        NaN
2015-01-10         NaN   0.1966458        NaN        NaN
2015-01-11         NaN         NaN  0.5135616        NaN
2015-01-12         NaN         NaN        NaN  0.3015004
2015-01-13         NaN         NaN  0.5717249        NaN
2015-01-14         NaN         NaN        NaN  0.5416951
2015-01-15         NaN         NaN  0.1031428        NaN
2015-01-16         NaN         NaN        NaN  0.2944353
2015-01-17         NaN         NaN   0.642031        NaN
2015-01-18         NaN         NaN        NaN  0.2546383
2015-01-19         NaN         NaN  0.6536632        NaN
2015-01-20         NaN         NaN        NaN  0.9877289
2015-01-21         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Now, because columns A and B are interleaved through a period of time with substantial overlap, I will treat those as comparable for analysis purposes.

Likewise, C and D data both occur over a time period of substantial overlap with each other, but zero overlap with the A/B time period.

I'm trying to come up with a slick way to identify A/B and C/D as pairs that go together. I could envision doing it with c.A.first_valid_index(), etc.... and this is all very algebraic if I go that way. I'm wondering if there is a slick way to do it using some built in "overlap" function from the time series tools. I could not find any such thing - hope it exists though. TIA

The code to make the contrived example DF above is:

```
t = pd.date_range('20150101',periods=21)
ti = t.to_datetime()

c = pd.DataFrame(index = ti, columns=['A','B','C','D'])

c.A[0:10:2] = np.random.rand(5)
c.B[1:11:2] = np.random.rand(5)
c.C[10:20:2] = np.random.rand(5)
c.D[11:21:2] = np.random.rand(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is wrong with using `.first_valid_index()` - looks slick enough to me:

```
periods = pd.Series([pd.date_range(c[col].first_valid_index(), 
                                   c[col].last_valid_index(), freq='D') 
                     for col in c.columns.tolist()], index=c.columns)
overlaps = periods.apply(lambda x: periods.apply(lambda y: x.isin(y).any()))
print overlaps
```

Gives an easy to use overlap matrix:

```
       A      B      C      D
A   True   True  False  False
B   True   True  False  False
C  False  False   True   True
D  False  False   True   True
```

Where it is trivial to check for overlap:

```
print overlaps.loc['A','B']
# True
print overlaps.loc['A','C']
# False
```

Or convert it to series:

```
overlaps = overlaps.stack()
print overlaps

A  A     True
   B     True
   C    False
   D    False
B  A     True
   B     True
   C    False
   D    False
C  A    False
   B    False
   C     True
   D     True
D  A    False
   B    False
   C     True
   D     True
dtype: bool
```

And access it without `.loc`:

```
print overlaps['A','B']
# True
print overlaps['A','C']
# False
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's on way to do.

Pass two-column combinations to the `overlap` function. What this does is

```
def overlap(cols):
    v = c[cols[0]].fillna(c[cols[1]]).notnull()
    days = (v[v].index.max() - v[v].index.min()).days + 1
    length = len(v[v])
    return 'Overlap' if length == days else 'No'
```

It will fill `NaN` values from `cols[0]` with `cols[1]`, `c[cols[0]].fillna(c[cols[1]])` and then extract non-null values only using `notnul()`

After which, find the `max` and `min` dates to get the date range  i.e `days`. And, then find out if length of the overlap series matches with `days`

---

Now, iterate over the column combination with `overlap(cols)`

```
In [14]: for cols in list(combinations(c.columns, 2)):
   ....:     print cols, overlap(cols)                
   ....:                                              
('A', 'B') Overlap                                    
('A', 'C') No                                         
('A', 'D') No                                         
('B', 'C') No                                         
('B', 'D') No
('C', 'D') Overlap
```